# LSF - BSUB Running a script if the job is killed

Tags: cluster-computing, job-scheduling, lsf

Im working with the LSF, running bsub commands.

I'm implementing the -Ep switch to run a post exec script. This works great until the Job is killed or hits a memory limit, run limit etc.

Is there any way for the job to detect its running out of resource and then run the script? or to force it to run the script even if its been killed?

I guess my other option is running job with a dependency on that job which will run the "post exec" script when it finishes.

Any thoughts?

Kind Regards,

TheBigPeeler

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSWRJV_10.1.0/lsf_admin/pre_post_exec_behaviour.html), you should be seeing the behaviour that you want.

> A post-execution command runs after the job finishes, regardless of
>   the exit state of the job. Once a post-execution command is associated
>   with a job, that command runs even if the job fails. You cannot
>   configure the post-execution command to run only under certain
>   conditions.

I thought that maybe the interaction with `JOB_INCLUDE_POSTEXEC` (lsb.params) could account for the difference, but from my test the post-exec still runs in both cases.  I used runlimit (`bsub -W`) to trigger the job kill.

Is it possible that the post exec is running, but exits early?

What version of LSF are you using?  (What's the output of `mbatchd -V` and `sbatchd -V`)